# Скрытие аккордеона при определённом размере экрана

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

У меня есть аккордеон на бутстрапе, при определённом размере экрана он по дефолту должен быть открыт, при определённом - закрыт.

```html
<button class="btn btn-info footerbutton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footer">
  Раскрыть аккордеон
</button>

<div class="collapse show" id="footer">
  что-то
</div>
```

Как мне это сделать? Хотел через постоянную проверку условия на js сделать

```js
  if (screen.width<1024) {
    $('#footer').attr('class','collapse hide')
  }
```

но не знаю как сделать так, чтобы проверка шла постоянно. Подскажите, как можно сделать? Можно ли как нибудь при помощи CSS и медиа запросов сделать?

Comment: У вас же бутстрап используется...посмотрите как на нем это реализовано. Фреймверки не только нужно юзать но и начинку знать. Откройте стили и все увидите сами. Можете поиграться с размерами экрана. Делается это через css

Comment: мне необходимо, чтобы при определённых размерах удалялся класс show, дабы аккордеон был скрыт. бутстраповский аккордеон завязан на этом классе

Comment: просто изменить что то у класса show не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удаление или добавление класса для определённых размеров экрана можно сделать следующим способом:

```
var $footer = $('#footer');

$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {

    // Проверяем наличие класса "hide"
    if (!$footer.hasClass('hide')) {

        // Устанавливаем новые классы
        $footer.attr('class', 'collapse hide');
    }
  }
  else {
    // Проверяем наличие класса "show"
    if (!$footer.hasClass('show')) {

        // Устанавливаем новые классы
        $footer.attr('class', 'collapse show');
    }
  }
});
```

Эта функция будет выполняться при загрузке страницы и при изменении её размера.

Comment: спасибо, то что надо

Answer (score -1):

Чистый `CSS` и `media` запросы

```
@media (max-width:454px) {
    /* тут прописываете css */
}
```